# Throw null exception when running fakes unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

fakes unit testing is very new to me. i never did it before so i decide to practice it but there are a problem that i cannot debug fakes unit testing because Shims.Context.Create() throw null Exception. When I run test, it worked but when I debug it, i got throw null exception. How to fix it?

**Class: FileReader**

```
namespace FakingExample
{
public class FileReader
{
    private readonly string _path;

    public FileReader(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Fakes Unit testing for FileReader Class:**

```
using System;
using FakingExample;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Fakes;
using Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes;

namespace FakingFileReader.Tests
{
  [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using (Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            // Arrange
            const string path = "irrelevant";
            const string expected = "contents";
            var target = new FileReader(path);

            // shim the FileStream constructor
            System.IO.Fakes.ShimFileStream.ConstructorStringFileMode =
                (@this, p, f) =>
                {
                    var shim = new System.IO.Fakes.ShimFileStream(@this);
                };

            // shim the StreamReader constructor
            System.IO.Fakes.ShimStreamReader.ConstructorStream =
                (@this, s) =>
                {
                    var shim = new System.IO.Fakes.ShimStreamReader(@this)
                    {
                        // shim the ReadToEnd method
                        ReadToEnd = () => expected
                    };
                };

            // Act
            var actual = target.Read();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please excuse the question, but why do you want to test this particular piece of code? It does not do anything of value on top of the .NET framework functionality. Nevertheless you are going through so much pain to test it, testing functionality that is already proven to be working. If you would be testing complex functionality of your own, you would write it so that fakes can be injected. Here it does not make sense.

Comment: If you can reliably recreate this problem, please create a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio with the complete source code of your project, including the .csproj, .fakes files.